# Developing an alert notification in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angular.js, controller

I'm studying Angular and want to develop my own notification alert. This is what I done, I like it and it's working like a charm but I think that it can be improved:

- Do I need to use it in conduction with a service? If yes, how?
- Will it be better if it became an E (element)?
- I needed to put `style="display: none;"` (see the HTML code) so it does not appear when the page is loaded and I think that it's not the best way. What do I do?
- How can I show and hide more classy, with some animation? CSS? Add/Remove [custom] class?

This is the directive:

```
myApp.directive('notification', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.notification = {
        status: 'hide',
        type: 'success',
        message: 'Welcome! It\'s yet another angular alert ;)'
      };
    }],
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // watch for changes
      attrs.$observe('notification', function (value) {
        if (value === 'show') {
          // shows alert
          $(elem).show();

          // and after 3secs
          $timeout(function () {
            // hide it
            $(elem).hide();

            // and update the show property
            scope.notification.status = 'hide';
          }, 3000);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{notification.type}}" style="display: none;" role="alert" data-notification="{{notification.status}}">{{notification.message}}</div>
```

A simple example on how to use it:

```
<button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="notification.status = 'show'; notification.message = 'Oh yeah!'; notification.type = 'info';">Show</button>
```

This is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBP9XVoFM6m07qkB4rqv?p=preview).

Comment: I did something similar myself a year ago. Was great to learn and I use it in production till today (there's even a major update coming soon). You my find some inspiration there: https://github.com/slacktracer/mercurius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple thing you can do is remove the need for the `$observe` and place the template inside the directive and use `ngShow` to handle the show/hide action.  (also added in scope that has two way binding to the `alertData` object.)

**Updated Directive**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.directive('notification', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template:"<div class='alert alert-{{alertData.type}}' ng-show='alertData.message' role='alert' data-notification='{{alertData.status}}'>{{alertData.message}}</div>",
            scope:{
              alertData:"="
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**And html**

```
<div class="container" style="width: 480px; margin-top: 50px;">
    <notification alert-data="notification"></notification>
<button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="notification.status = 'show'; notification.message = 'Oh yeah!'; notification.type = 'info';">Show</button>
```

**[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/84L4fh75s2lImztSNgLZ?p=preview)**